# Wordpress - Display recent posts in two separated divs/columns

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to display the recent posts in WP. Where I want the recent posts to be displayed in two separated divs or columns. I am not sure how to do it. Now it posts the same in both of the divs.

The divs are set up using Bootstrap.

I have also a problem with the get_the_post_thumbnail, it does not work:

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail($header_thumb->ID);?>
```

I will also want to have it so just 10 of the first blogpost will be seen. Then the user must push a botton "Read more posts", and more posts will be loaded below.

```
<div id="blogg" class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="blogg_innlegg_left" class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-3"><div class="well">
            <ul>
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php get_the_post_thumbnail($header_thumb->ID);?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250);?></li>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </ul>
        </div></div>
        <div id="blogg_innlegg_right" class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-3"><div class="well">
            <ul>
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
                <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php get_the_post_thumbnail($header_thumb->ID);?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250);?></li>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </ul>
        </div></div>
        <div id="blogg_sidebar" class="col col-lg-4 col-sm-4"><div class="well">
            <p>Sidebar will be placed here</p>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but as you should do as few queries as possible, you need to use query rewind functions that Wordpress provides, I recommend this reading -> http://digwp.com/2011/09/3-ways-to-reset-the-wordpress-loop/

However for the purpose, I've corrected your code by creating 2 different queries with the one offsetting the first 5 posts that are already appearing on the left column. You were showing the same query on both sides and that is not possible.

```
<div id="blogg" class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="blogg_innlegg_left" class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-3"><div class="well">
            <ul>
                <?php $left_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5' ); ?>
                <?php while ($left_query -> have_posts()) : $left_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250);?></li>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </ul>
        </div></div>
        <div id="blogg_innlegg_right" class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-3"><div class="well">
            <ul>
                <?php $right_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=5&offset=5' ); ?>
                <?php while ($right_query -> have_posts()) : $right_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250);?></li>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </ul>
        </div></div>
        <div id="blogg_sidebar" class="col col-lg-4 col-sm-4"><div class="well">
            <p>Sidebar will be placed here</p>
        </div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've corrected the thumbnail to show the Featured image.
About the read more, it will really depend on your template but as you are saying I believe what you want is a jQuery loader, and that is a different question.

For the main question, the reply is above.